# Java Swing. При наступлении события (воспроизведение ноты 127) вместе с объектом типа Graphics заново рисуются все компоненты фрейма

Tags: java, swing, события, аудио, bufferedimage

Пример из Head First Java. Суть программы - при нажатии на кнопку воспроизводятся ноты, в такт которым на панели MyDrawPanel panelFigure рисуются прямоугольники. Но вместе с ними почему-то в панели для рисования рисуются копии компонентов фрейма. В результате панель для рисования сдвигается вниз и вправо.
Применяя правило непрозрачности и метод super.paintComponent(), артефакты пропадают, но фигуры на экране рисуются по одной, не сохраняя предыдущие. Мне нужно,чтобы предыдущие рисунки сохранялись. Как убрать артефакты при сохранении предыдущих фигур?

**Программа при запуске кода**

[image: Программа при запуске кода]

**Фрейм после воспроизведения**

[image: Фрейм после воспроизведения]

Код программы.

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MiniMusicPlayer5 {

MyDrawPanel panelFigure;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiniMusicPlayer5 mini = new MiniMusicPlayer5();
    mini.getGuiPanel();
}

public void getGuiPanel() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Мой первый музыкальный фильм");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    // Создаём панель танца фигур.
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Танцпол");
    label.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    JPanel panelDance = new JPanel();
    panelDance.setBackground(Color.gray);
    Dimension d1 = new Dimension(400, 340);
    panelDance.setPreferredSize(d1);
    panelDance.setMaximumSize(d1);
    panelDance.setAlignmentX(JPanel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    panelFigure = new MyDrawPanel(); // Создаём панель для рисования.
    panelDance.add(panelFigure);

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelMain.add(label);
    panelMain.add(panelDance);
    panelMain.revalidate();
    panelMain.repaint();
    panelMain.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 20));

    // Создаём панель кнопки.
    JButton buttonPlay = new JButton("Проиграть");
    buttonPlay.addActionListener(new ButtonPlayListener());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(60, 20, 0, 20));
    panel.add(panelMain);
    panel.add(buttonPlay);

    // Создаём фрейм.
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
} // Конец setUpGui().

public class ButtonPlayListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();
            player.addControllerEventListener(panelFigure, new int[]{127});
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
                int note = (int) ((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
                if (note < 38) {
                    track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, note, 100, i));
                    track.add(makeEvent(176, 1, 127, 0, i));
                    track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, note, 100, i + 2));
                }
            }
            player.setSequence(seq);
            player.setTempoInBPM(180);
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} // Конец play().

public MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
    MidiEvent event = null;
    try {
        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
        event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return event;
} // Конец MidiEvent makeEvent().

// Панель для рисования - это теперь слушатель.
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel implements ControllerEventListener {
    // Присваиваем флагу значение "false" и будем устанавливать "true",
    // когда получим cобытие.
    boolean msg = false;

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 340);
    }

    // Метод обработки события из интерфейса слушателя.
    public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
        // Получаем событие, присвоив флагу значение "true" и вызвав repaint().
        msg = true;
        repaint();
    } // Конец controlChange(ShortMessage event).

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Используем флаг msg, чтобы рисование срабатывало только при наступлении 
        // события ControllerEvent, а другие объекты не могли запустить repaint().
        if (msg) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Случайный цвет.
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            g2.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));

            // Случайное положение фигуры.
            int x = (int) ((Math.random() * 200) + 30);
            int y = (int) ((Math.random() * 170) + 90);
            int width = (int) ((Math.random() * 200) + 0);
            int height = (int) ((Math.random() * 170) + 0);
            g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            msg = false;
        } // Закрываем if.
    } // Конец метода paintComponent(Graphics g).
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью буферизации с использованием класса BufferedImage. Помогли решить мой вопрос ответы на данные вопросы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132988/painting-in-a-bufferedimage-inside-swing и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683533/drawing-a-rectangle-that-wont-disappear-in-next-paint/12683601#12683601.
Также помог пример в конце данной статьи - https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/akademicheskii/tsifrovaia-obrabotka-izobrazhenii-s-ispolzovaniem-java/klass-java-bufferedimage.
Также пришлось вернуться ко второй версии кода MiniMusicPlayer в книге "Head First Java 2".

Окончательный код:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MiniMusicPlayer5 {
private BufferedImage panelFigure;
private JPanel dancePanel;
private RenderingHints renderingHints;
private boolean msg = false;
private DrawFigure drawFigure;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new MiniMusicPlayer5().getGuiPanel());
}

public void getGuiPanel() {
    Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object> hintsMap = new HashMap<>();
    hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    hintsMap.put(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    renderingHints = new RenderingHints(hintsMap);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Танцы фигур");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder
            (60, 20, 0, 20));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Танцпол");
    label.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    // Создаём панель танца фигур.
    panelFigure = new BufferedImage
            (400, 340, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    dancePanel = new JPanel();
    dancePanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    Dimension d1 = new Dimension(400, 340);
    dancePanel.setPreferredSize(d1);
    dancePanel.setMaximumSize(d1);
    dancePanel.setAlignmentX(JPanel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    dancePanel.setOpaque(true);

    drawFigure = new DrawFigure();

    dancePanel.add(drawFigure, null);

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panelMain.add(label);
    panelMain.add(dancePanel);
    panelMain.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder
            (0, 0, 0, 20));

    // Создаём кнопку.
    JButton buttonPlay = new JButton("Проиграть");
    buttonPlay.addActionListener(new ButtonPlayListener());

    panel.add(panelMain);
    panel.add(buttonPlay);

    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(600, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
} // Конец getGuiPanel().

public class ButtonPlayListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();
            player.addControllerEventListener(drawFigure, new int[]{127});
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 4) {
                int note = (int) ((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
                if (note < 38) {
                    track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.
                            NOTE_ON, 1, note, 100), i));
                    track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.
                            CONTROL_CHANGE, 1, 127, 0), i));
                    track.add(new MidiEvent(new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.
                            NOTE_OFF, 1, note, 100), i + 2));
                }
            }
            player.setSequence(seq);
            player.setTempoInBPM(180);
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class DrawFigure extends JPanel implements ControllerEventListener {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Image img = createImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 0,0,this);
    }

    private Image createImage() {
        Graphics g = panelFigure.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
        if (msg) {
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            g2.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));

            // Случайное положение фигуры.
            int x = (int) ((Math.random() * 200) + 20);
            int y = (int) ((Math.random() * 170) + 20);
            int width = (int) ((Math.random() * 200) + 0);
            int height = (int) ((Math.random() * 170) + 0);
            g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            msg = false;
        }
        return panelFigure;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 340);
    }

    // Метод обработки события из интерфейса слушателя.
    public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
        // Получаем событие, присвоив флагу значение "true" и вызвав...
        // repaint().
        msg = true;
        dancePanel.repaint();
        dancePanel.revalidate();
    } // Конец controlChange(ShortMessage event).
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]